# How to define the objective and constraint function for linear regression in gurobi?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have a numpy array x with 10000 rows * 10 columns and a vector y.  Now I want to build a linear regression model [image: img1] using gurobi and python. My goal is to minimize the worst possible absolute value of error.

[image: img2]

I am really new to gurobi, so after adding all decision variables (w1, ...w10 and b) to model I stuck at writing objective and constraint functions. For constraint function part, I think I should create a 10000*1 numpy variable z to represent the error.

```
for i in range(10000):
    m.addConstr(np.dot(x[i],w) + b - y[i] - z[i], "<=" , rhs=0)  
    m.addConstr(-(np.dot(x[i],w) + b - y[i]) - z[i], "<=" , rhs=0)
m.update()

m.optimize()
```

But I am straggled that which initial value I should set to z. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: `z` must be a decision variable, so no initial value is needed.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Another question is if I want to get the worst error in z, can I just use max(z) or I have to add another variable z_max and add corresponding constraint?

Comment: You can't use max. You need to formulate it according to the rules of your modelling-framework. But to be honest: your norm is still missing (and one might think about those re-formulations keeping both parts in mind).

Comment: Yes, you need a variable `z_max` and equations `z<=z_max`. Then minimize `z_max`.

Comment: Finally, I got it. Thank you for you guys.

Comment: Nb there are better formulations for this. First thing one can do is to replace z[i] by a single z and minimize z directly.

Comment: It is a precise and concise formulation, which just reduces adding variables and  constraints dramatically. Thanks.